# Why can't I convert the `svg` data to UIImage using `SVGKit` in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, svg, uiimage, svgkit

I'm trying to convert my `svg` image data to `UIImage` instance using `SVGKit`, but when I'm trying to do this its getting crashed, and the error message is like below:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Asked to convert a Percentage value to a different type (5)'

Here is the code for `svg` to `UIImage` conversion.

```
if let data = response.data {
    if let image = SVGKImage(data: data) {
       if let uiImageInstance = image.uiImage {
           self.userImageView.image = uiImageInstance
       }
    }
}
```

Its getting crashed at this line

```
->  if let uiImageInstance = image.uiImage {
```

I'm using `AlamofireImage` library for downloading my image data from server.

I have checked that my `svg` data is there in response.

**FYI:** My image is combination of avatar letters and gradient background.

See below image for reference.

[image]

**My svg image sample URL:** [Link](https://avatar.tobi.sh/unknown?size=120&type=svg&text=SI)

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this line is wrong `if let uiImage = image.uiImage {` ensure once property name

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I have tried by having different property name as well. Its not worked.

Comment: why you used two safer one is enough here

Comment: Can you please make it clear

Comment: what the response you get here `let image =`

Comment: Here `image` is SVGKImage's instance.

Comment: can you print that

Comment: Could you please update your SVG URL here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are image is using gradient effect then it will not work in SVGKit. Check whether your image is using any gradient effect.

> Apple's rendering DOES NOT ALLOW US to render this image correctly
>   using SVGKFastImageView, because Apple's renderInContext method -
>   according to Apple's docs - ignores Apple's own masking layers. Until
>   Apple fixes this bug, you should use SVGKLayeredImageView for this
>   particular SVG file (or avoid using gradients)

Comment: Yes, my image is combination of letters and gradient.

Comment: I can get one from the service what im using. So I decided to go with png rather than svg. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please do the following:

1. First of all,check the **response.data**(is it the correct
   format you are expecting?)
2. Try to use **image.UIImage** instead of **image.uiImage**